# n-cocycles of finite abelian groups from cohomology group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, finite-groups, group-cohomology

**Question:** Given a generic finite abelian group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{N^{(1)}} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{N^{(k)}}$.

**(1) What is the explicit forms of its [cohomology group (see my definition)](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dijkgraaf-Witten+theory) in a generic $n$:**
$$
H^n(G,R/\mathbb{Z})=H^n(G,U(1)) =?
$$

**(2) what are their explicit $n$-cocycles?**
$$
\omega_{}^{}(A_1,A_2,\dots, A_n): (G)^n \to U(1)
$$

Please be very explicit in $n=4$ for priority (and the secondary are $n=5$ and $n=2$) of interests. But the generic formulas for any $n$ are the best. Thank you. References are very welcome.

**ps. below I provide the answer I know for $n=3$. Please feel free providing partial answers for other $n$.**

Comment: Using the Long exact sequence for the short exact sequence $O\to Z\to R\to U(1)\to 0$ and the fact that G is finite and R divisible, youncan reduce to computing cohomology with values in Z. Then you can use the Künneth formula, you get reduced to computing the cohomology of cyclic groups, and that is explained in every textbook. If you want explicit cocycles, that's more work, but the Künneth formula is actually explicit, and gives you explicit cocycles built out of cup products.

Comment: Thanks Mariano, I know how to compute cohomology group. But I wonder whether there are **explicit formulas for them** (i.e. people already computed in the literature? such as my answer below)? n-cocycles need to solve cocycle conditions, so are there known results in any Ref?

Comment: The computation is of course known and, by now, part of folklore: it is probably easier to carry out the sketch in my comment above than go looking for references. (I can't make a lot of sense of your answer, by the way) Moreover, everything I wrote above is as explicit as things come.

Comment: Dear Mariano, thanks. It will be helpful if you can explicitly give a **reference (also page number) on this step "Explicit cocycles built out of cup products.**"  I certainly had computed the n-th cohomology group using UTC and Kunneth formula. But solving cocycles-conditions and check whether those cocycles are indeed independent (independent up to coboundaries) matching the cohomology group, this is a less-trivial step than the original naive thinking. (ps. I am a theoretical physicist, not mathematician. thanks!)

Comment: also to Mariano your: (I can't make a lot of sense of your answer). If you cannot understand my answer, then perhaps you do not really know the nontrivial part of this question. (Though not saying this is a difficult question. I believe it is straitforward.)

Comment: For example, if $k=1$, the formula you wrote for $H^3$ gives zero. Yet $H^3(G,\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $H^4(G,\mathbb Z)$, which is not zero because  G is cyclic. Apart from that, most of the notation in your description of cocycles is not explained at all, and what is explained I don't understand (what do you mean by «labels», the brackets plainly do more than group terms, A, B and C only appear on the left hand sides of your equations , &c), so I cannot really tell if the formula is correct or not, because it does not mean anything to me!

Comment: those are Dijkgraff-Witten theory and 2+1D Chern-Simons theory; and TQFT, topological orders to me. $p$ "labels" $Z_N$ means $p \in Z_N$.

Comment: ps. it is also very discouraging for me, a physicist, posting a question here, got downvoted; but without getting back a proper answer. (imagine you try friendly to write a question in Phys.SE. on quantum field theory or quantum mechanics, and people downvote you there.)

Comment: I have no idea what D-W theory is, nor the rest, really. Reading through the nlab ---as it most often happens to me--- has not helped and that page is rather opaque to me, but I did gather that the relevant cohomology theory for groups in that context is the usual one, and about *that* I do know something at least. As I said above, if I compute the 3rd cohomology group, I get something rather different. I have assumed so far, as I said, that the problem is that *I* cannot understand what you wrote, and you seem to agree. Oh well.

Comment: What I have, is the same as yours, $H^3(G,R/Z)=H^4(G,Z)$ and $H^3(Z_N,R/Z)=H^4(Z_N,Z)=Z_N$ and $p_I$ labels the $Z_N$ element. What I mean is $p_I \in Z_N$. My answer below is the desired 3-cocycle, and also for 3-cocycles of cohomology group H^4 of other more general cyclic groups G.

Comment: If k=1, the direct sum in your answer is zero, for there are no terms.

Comment: in that case, $1=i=k=1$, and there is no $j,l$.

Comment: Exeo. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12582/discussion-between-idear-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 years later.

My recent paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03266) answers this question.

More precisely,
let $\mathbb{k}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. By $\mathbb{k}^*$ we denote the multiplicative group $\mathbb{k}-\{0\}$. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{m_{1}}\times\cdots \times\mathbb{Z}_{m_{n}}$ where $m_i|m_{i+1}$ for $1\le i\le n-1$ and $(B_{\bullet},\partial_{\bullet})$ be its normalized bar resolution.
Applying $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}G}(-,\mathbb{k}^*)$ one gets a complex $(B^*_{\bullet},\partial^*_{\bullet})$.

Let $\alpha:=(\alpha_{11},\dots,\alpha_{1n},\dots,\alpha_{k1},\dots,\alpha_{kn})$ where $0\leq\alpha_{ij}<m_{j}$ for $1\leq i\leq k$.
For $1\leq r\leq n$, $[a,b]\subseteq[1,k]$, $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha$, denote

$$
\eta_{r,[a,b]}^{\alpha}:=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}[\frac{\alpha_{br}+\alpha_{b-1,r}}{m_{r}}]\cdots[\frac{\alpha_{a+1,r}+\alpha_{ar}}{m_{r}}]&\;\;\;a-b\text{ odd}\\
[\frac{\alpha_{br}+\alpha_{b-1,r}}{m_{r}}]\cdots[\frac{\alpha_{a+2,r}+\alpha_{a+1,r}}{m_{r}}]\alpha_{ar}&\;\;\;a-b\text{ even}
\end{array}\right.
$$
The following $\omega\in \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}G}(B_k,\mathbb{k}^*)$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\omega([g_1^{\alpha_{11}}\cdots g_n^{\alpha_{1n}},\dots,g_1^{\alpha_{k1}}\cdots g_n^{\alpha_{kn}}])\\\notag
&=&\prod_{l=1}^{k}\prod_{\begin{array}{ccc}1\leq r_{1}<\cdots<r_{l}\leq n\\\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_l=k,\lambda_1\text{ odd}\\\lambda_i\ge1\text{ for }1\le i\le l\end{array}}\zeta_{m_{r_1}}^{(-1)^{\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq l}\lambda_{i}\lambda_{j}}\eta_{r_{1},[a_{1},b_{1}]}^{\alpha}\cdots\eta_{r_{l},[a_{l},b_{l}]}^{\alpha}a_{r_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots r_l^{\lambda_l}}}
\end{eqnarray}
where $a_{l}=1,b_{l}=\lambda_{l},\dots,a_{1}=\lambda_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{l}+1,b_{1}=\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\lambda_{l}=k$ and $0\leq a_{r_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots r_l^{\lambda_l}}<m_{r_1}$ for $1\leq r_1<\cdots<r_l\leq n$
makes a complete set of representatives of $k$-cocycles of the complex $(B_{\bullet}^*,\partial_{\bullet}^*)$.
Moreover,
$$\text{H}^k(G,\mathbb{k}^*)=\prod_{r=1}^n\mathbb{Z}_{m_r}^{\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{k+j}\binom{n-r+j-1}{j-1}}.$$

Comment: Nice answer and congrats on your paper!

Comment: Very excellent paper. See page 10-12 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7689 (in Phys Rev Lett). They derive essential the similar formulas from quantum fields. And also https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04264. Both results are consistent and deal with the similar issues you have.

Answer (score 4):

An algorithmic way to describe the standard n-cocycle (cocycles respect to the bar resolution) for abelian groups is given in Lyndon's paper [The cohomology theory of group extensions](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077474679) (It is no more than the LHS spectral sequences in a very particular case).As Mariano said, first you need to describe the n-cocycles for cyclic groups (constructing a chain homomorphism between the cyclic resolution and the Bar resolution). After that you only need to follow the ideas of Lyndon's paper in order to construct explicitly the standard n-cocycles.

By the way, in Lyndon's paper also there is an explicit description of $H^{n}(A,U(1))\cong H^{n+1}(A,\mathbb{Z})$ for $A$ a finite abelian group.

Answer (score 2):

(**Not a complete answer.**) Let me say what I have tried in $n=3$ (**this is only a partial answer I already know**).

Given a generic finite abelian group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{N^{(1)}} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{N^{(k)}}$. I compute that 3rd-cohomology group is 
$$
H^3(G,R/\mathbb{Z}) 
\simeq \! \bigoplus_{1 \leq i < j < l \leq k} \! Z_{N^{(i)}}
         \oplus Z_{{\gcd} (N^{(i)},N^{(j)})}
         \oplus Z_{{\gcd} (N^{(i)},N^{(j)},N^{(l)})} \, . 
$$ ($R/\mathbb{Z}=U(1)$)

I also compute the corresponding 3-cocycles are:
$$
\omega_{{I}}^{(i)}(A,B,C)    = 
\exp \left( \frac{2 \pi i p^{(i)}_{{I}}}{N^{(i)\;2}} \;
a^{(i)}(b^{(i)} +c^{(i)} -[b^{(i)}+c^{(i)}]) \right) 
\\
\omega_{{II}}^{(ij)}(A,B,C) =             
\exp \left( 
\frac{2 \pi i p_{{II}}^{(ij)}}{N^{(i)}N^{(j)}}  \;
a^{(i)}(b^{(j)} +c^{(j)} - [b^{(j)}+c^{(j)}]) \right)  \\
\omega_{{III}}^{(ijl)} (A,B,C) = \exp \left( \frac{2 \pi i
p_{{III}}^{(ijl)}}{{\gcd}(N^{(i)}, N^{(j)},N^{(l)})} \;
a^{(i)}b^{(j)}c^{(l)} \right)
$$
with $p^{(i)}_{{I}}$ labels the group element $Z_{N^{(i)}}$, $p_{{II}}^{(ij)}$ labels the group element in $Z_{{\gcd} (N^{(i)},N^{(j)})}$ and $p_{{III}}^{(ijl)}$ labels the group element in $Z_{{\gcd} (N^{(i)},N^{(j)},N^{(l)})}$.

I am still interested in knowing other $n$, especially $n=2,4,5$. Please reply in the specific forms in $n=3$ as I did for $H^3(G,R/\mathbb{Z})$ and $\omega$. Thank you.

Comment: ps. this won't be the final answer. Just a partial result on $n=3$. Please help on generic $n$ or $n=4$. Many thanks.

Comment: Here $A=(a^{(1)},a^{(2)},\dots,a^{(k)})$, and so does $B,C$ define the same way. Here $[b^{(i)}+c^{(i)}] \equiv (b^{(i)}+c^{(i)}) \text{mod} Z_N^{(i)}$.